# Slicing DataFrame by duplicate period indexes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Slice DataFrame by period indexes of Pandas, when
the period indices are unique, the slicing is OK,
But when the period indices are duplicate, the slicing will cause exception:

## TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Period' with type 'int',

The following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
df=DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5],columns=["value"])
#generate unique period index for dataframe
index=pd.PeriodIndex([2001,2002,2003,2004,2005],freq="A")
df.index=index;
df.loc[pd.Period(2002):pd.Period(2004)] #is ok

#generate duplicate period index for dataframe
index=pd.PeriodIndex([2001,2001,2003,2004,2005],freq="A")
df.index=index;
df.loc[pd.Period(2002):pd.Period(2004)]
#TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Period' with type 'int'
```

Comment: The code provided worked without errors when I tested (on python 3.8.2, with pandas 1.0.5)